# mvc 4 add custom header conditionally (using web config)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, cross-domain

I want to be able to use the cutomHeaders in the .net mvc 4 web config file, but I want it to be applied only to requests that match a certain condition.
Specifically if the request is for an html file, or fits a certain route (goes to a certain folder).

Please help, it will solve me so may problems.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have specific `controllers/actions` on which this custom header needs to be applied? Is so you can write a simple `ActionFilter` where you add the headers in `OnResultExecuted`.

Comment: It is not on a controller, I am familiar with that option. It is for static files reuests.